# Operating Leverage Interpretation

Tags: quants, leverage, margin, capital-structure

Operating Leverage is the ratio of Contribution margin and operating income(proxy of profit).

So, Operating Leverage = [Sales-Variable Cost]/[Profit] = Quantity*(Price-AVC)/Profit

Many literature including investopedia, CFA curriculum suggests that if operating leverage is k, then if sales go up by a%, the profit will go up by k times a% = ak%

But, if I use the formula, Sales going up by a% implies, quantity going up by a% as price and AVC are fixed. Then, how come Profit will increase by ak%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operating leverage $k$:
$$k=\frac{Quantity*(Price-AVC)}{Profit}$$
but profit (actually operating profit) is:
$$Profit=Quantity*(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts$$
If quantity sold increases by $a\%$ then our new profit is:
$$Profit_{new}=Quantity*(Price-AVC)(1+a)-FixOpCosts$$
Percentage change in Profit is:
$$Profit_{new}/Profit-1$$
Then you are basically asking if
$$ka\stackrel{?}{=}Profit_{new}/Profit-1$$

It is just simple algebra to show that it holds
$$ka\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{Profit_{new}}{Profit}-1$$
$$ka\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{Quantity*(Price-AVC)(1+a)-FixOpCosts}{Quantity*(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}-1$$
$$ka\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{Quantity*(Price-AVC)(1+a)-FixOpCosts}{Quantity*(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}-\frac{Quantity*(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}{Quantity*(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}$$

$$ka\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{Q(Price-AVC)a}{Q(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}$$
Given our definition of k we have:
$$\frac{Quantity(Price-AVC)}{Profit}a\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{Q(Price-AVC)a}{Q(Price-AVC)-FixOpCosts}$$

Given our definition of $Profit$ we see that it in fact holds:
$$ka{=}\frac{Profit_{new}}{Profit}-1$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was using CM(new)/Profit(new)=k. But, didn't realize that will not hold. Thanks for breaking it down.